# How to enable CORS on DIVSHOT?

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, header, cors, divshot

I've been struggling with the `Access-Allow-Control-Origin`, I am using Divshot. In my mobile app I am displaying the posts of WordPress Account, when I test my app in the browser, I can see the posts, but once I open the app in Chrome for mobile, I am unable to see the posts. According to what I saw, there is some people with the same issue, so I need to use CORS in the Divshot config file.

In the Divshot page, [this is what they say](http://docs.divshot.com/guides/routing), but I don't know how to do it in my app

```
Custom Headers
If you need to set custom response headers for specific routes,
you can use the headers key in your configuration file:

{
  "headers": {
    "/cors-stuff/**": {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    "/scripts/**": {
      "content-type": "text/javascript"
    }
  }
}

This can be useful for applying a content security policy, enforcing a different content-type, enabling cross-origin resource sharing (CORS), and more.
```

and this is what I have in my config file

```
{
  "name": "urbanetradio",
  "root": "www",
  "clean_urls": true,
  "error_page": "error.html",
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "/js/**": {
      "content-type": "text/javascript"
    }
  }
}
```

but still I don't have any good result.

Comment: your code isn't the same... they have an object `"/cors-stuff/**"` with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as a property of it, you have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as a property of the `headers`.

Comment: but what they mean with ```cors-stuff```??? @Claies should I put the same in my config file ?

Comment: seems that it's something internal to their platform.  What did their support say?

Comment: lot of stuff here https://divshot.com/blog/static-apps/cookies-and-cors/ but the juice is here http://docs.divshot.com/guides/routing

Comment: yes, but you said you tried what they recommended and it didn't work.  So did you try e-mailing their support department?

Comment: @Claies not yet. Let me see if I do it just right now. There is no much info in the web about Divshot

Comment: I would try their headers in the *exact* format that is listed on their website, and include that extra key, even if you don't think it's necessary or don't understand what it is... they listed it there for a reason.

Comment: @Claies I have a plunkr already http://plnkr.co/edit/KlfmqW2eLDdEhf90Dsuy?p=preview, open de the console you can see this ```XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:8100' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access.```

Comment: @Claies it is the same in the app, but instead of ```Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co'```you see ```Origin 'http://localhost:8100'```

Comment: well, since `http://run.plnkr.co` is your client, and `urbanetradio.com` is your server, and `http://localhost:8100` wouldn't be accessible on the web, this seems to be something misconfigured on the server.  Again, it seems e-mailing their support would best shed light on this.

Comment: @Claies it seem as If I have to set ```<? header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>``` at WP side, and I don't have access to that part,  would have to talk to the WP's owner.

Comment: You really need to get a better understanding of what CORS means. It is the API endpoint that needs to be enabled if you use ajax. Otherwise use your server as proxy to get the data and return it to you

Comment: @charlietfl I am not the owner of the WP where I am requesting the posts from. So if I get this terminology, I need to set that in the server side, in this case the WP account, so I need to set up something like this: ```<? header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>```

Comment: You keep trying to work around something you can't do.  It makes no difference what is set on your site...it's the remote api that matters. You have no choice but to use a proxy to get the data if the remote site is not CORS enabled or serves jsonp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just in case someone wants to know, at time of doing the request you have to send more params, look at the example, I have it working now

```
getBlogs: function($scope) {
  $scope.postsURL = 'http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';
  $http.jsonp($scope.postsURL).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(config);
    $scope.posts = data;
  }).error(function(data, status_headers, config) {
      console.log('error');
  });
}
```